# Is it possible to change the display name in Finder Favourites?

Tags: macos, finder, sidebar

I have added a number of folders to the Favourites in the Finder sidebar.

Is it possible to change the actual display name from the original folder name?

Answer (score 2):

I have an idea how to do it 
Choose your folder that you want to add to the favourites sidebar
Make an alias of that folder and rename it as you want
[image]

Then add this alias folder to the favourites sidebar

Comment: I just tested this out (on macOS Ventura 13.4) and it does work, although you'll need to remove the original shortcut from your sidebar before trying to add the alias to the sidebar. For some reason if you try to add both the original folder and an alias to the sidebar at the same time, Finder will treat them as identical, and the existing shortcut will just get moved to the position where you dragged the new item.